# Split date result sets into columns in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

can you please assist

I have a query that shows number of teachers, the site the visited and when date they visited. This query looks at all teachers visits for the past week.

I want to split the dateattended field into columns to show daily visit for the past week. Below is how it looks.

```
EmployeeNumber  Name                    HomeSite    Site Attended   Day Attended
TP-000322789    Samuel Mohlamnyane  Teacher          Port Elizabeth 2014-10-18 07:23
TP-000148774    Jean Smoothie           Teacher      Hennopsview    2014-10-13 08:55
TP-000148774    Jean Smoothie           Teacher      Hennopsview    2014-10-16 08:43
TP-000148122    Anthony Mike            Teacher      Tzaneen        2014-10-19 09:19
TP-000148122    Anthony Mike            Teacher      Tzaneen        2014-10-15 08:26
TP-000328452    Geneve Gorridon         Teacher      Tzaneen        2014-10-14 07:44
TP-000346529    Edmos Dube              Teacher      Melrose        2014-10-18 07:47
TP-000321374    Anita Rene Classen      Teacher      Johannesburg   2014-10-17 07:57
TP-000324511    Anthonysia White        Teacher      Durbanville    2014-10-15 07:53
TP-000324511    Anthonysia White        Teacher      Durbanville    2014-10-18 12:26
TP-000327471    Moses Mathebula         Teacher      Polokwane      2014-10-13 05:50
TP-000148194    Nonhlanhla Ndlovu       Teacher      Vereeniging    2014-10-15 07:06
TP-000323383    Lerato Manyanka         Teacher      Bedfordview    2014-10-13 07:26
TP-000323383    Lerato Manyanka         Teacher      Bedfordview    2014-10-16 06:51
TP-000323384    Lerato Manyanka         Teacher      Bedfordview    2014-10-17 08:57
```

Now I want to split Day attended to show date in different columns from yesterday going down to the last seven days.

Below is the code I used to get the above result set. And how the result should look like.

```
EmployeeNumber Name              HomeSite   Site Attended   Day 1  Day2    Day 3             Day 4             Day 5                Day 6            Day 7 
TP-000148194   Nonhlanhla Ndlovu Teacher    Vereeniging                                                        2014-10-15 07:06
TP-000323383   Lerato Manyanka   Teacher    Bedfordview                    2014-10-17 08:57  2014-10-16 06:51                                     2014-10-13 07:26  



SELECT   mdet.MemRefNo                        AS 'EmployeeNumber'
       , cont.FirstName + ' ' + cont.LastName AS Name 
       , s.Name                               AS 'HomeSite'
       , Attend.VisitedSite                   AS 'Site Attended'
       , Attend.Weekdays                      AS 'Day Attended'

FROM MemberDetail mdet
INNER JOIN MembershipHistory mhis ON mdet.CurrentMembershipID = mhis.ID32
INNER JOIN contacts cont ON cont.GUID = mdet.ContactGUID
INNER JOIN Sites s ON s.id = cont.HomeSiteID

INNER JOIN Packages pg ON pg.ID = mhis.PackageID


 CROSS APPLY
 (
SELECT min(a1.attenddate) AS Weekdays , a1.contactguid, a1.SiteID , s.Name as VisitedSite       FROM dbo.attendance a1
    INNER JOIN Sites s ON s.id = a1.Siteid 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,a1.attenddate,GETDATE()) <= 7
and ContactGuid = mdet.ContactGuid  
AND a1.isswipesuccessful = 1
GROUP BY a1.ContactGuid, DATEPART(DW, a1.attenddate),a1.SiteID , s.Name
) Attend

WHERE pg.Description LIKE '%Teacher%'
```

Comment: Can you edit the question adding an example of what the new columns should look like?

Comment: Hi there I have edited the above query to show how this should look

Comment: OK, so you've already written a select. Does it produce the results you want? Is it close?

Comment: @user1538257 What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the query you want, it uses a pivot with the results from your existing query as source through a common table expression. Ideally the code could be merged into one query, but as you didn't provide any test data from the source tables, but only the output I didn't try to rewrite it. Note that if a person visited the same site more than one time in a single day, only the latest time will be shown.

```
-- using original query as source
;WITH visits AS (
    SELECT   mdet.MemRefNo                        AS 'EmployeeNumber'
         , cont.FirstName + ' ' + cont.LastName AS Name 
         , s.Name                               AS 'HomeSite'
         , Attend.VisitedSite                   AS 'Site Attended'
         , Attend.Weekdays                      AS 'Day Attended'

    FROM MemberDetail mdet
    INNER JOIN MembershipHistory mhis ON mdet.CurrentMembershipID = mhis.ID32
    INNER JOIN contacts cont ON cont.GUID = mdet.ContactGUID
    INNER JOIN Sites s ON s.id = cont.HomeSiteID
    INNER JOIN Packages pg ON pg.ID = mhis.PackageID
    CROSS APPLY
    (
    SELECT min(a1.attenddate) AS Weekdays , a1.contactguid, a1.SiteID , s.Name as VisitedSite       FROM dbo.attendance a1
       INNER JOIN Sites s ON s.id = a1.Siteid 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,a1.attenddate,GETDATE()) <= 7
    and ContactGuid = mdet.ContactGuid  
    AND a1.isswipesuccessful = 1
    GROUP BY a1.ContactGuid, DATEPART(DW, a1.attenddate),a1.SiteID , s.Name
    ) Attend
    WHERE pg.Description LIKE '%Teacher%'   
)

-- query to produce results
SELECT 
    EmployeeNumber, 
    Name, 
    HomeSite, 
    [Site Attended],
    [1] AS 'Day 1',
    [2] AS 'Day 2',
    [3] AS 'Day 3',
    [4] AS 'Day 4',
    [5] AS 'Day 5',
    [6] AS 'Day 6',
    [7] AS 'Day 7'
FROM (
    SELECT *, DATEDIFF(day, [Day Attended], GETDATE()) diff 
    FROM visits
    WHERE [Day Attended] > (GETDATE()-7) -- adjust this to limit date range
    ) a
PIVOT (
    MAX([Day Attended]) FOR [diff] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])
) AS Pivoted;
```

It would probably be trivial to modify the existing query to get the desired results.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20f20/1) (using the sample output data as source).

Sample results:

```
EmployeeNumber       Name                                     HomeSite             Site Attended        Day 1                   Day 2                   Day 3                   Day 4                   Day 5                   Day 6                   Day 7
-------------------- ---------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
TP-000148122         Anthony Mike                             Teacher              Tzaneen              NULL                    2014-10-19 09:19:00.000 NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    2014-10-15 08:26:00.000 NULL
TP-000148194         Nonhlanhla Ndlovu                        Teacher              Vereeniging          NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    2014-10-15 07:06:00.000 NULL
TP-000148774         Jean Smoothie                            Teacher              Hennopsview          NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    2014-10-16 08:43:00.000 NULL                    NULL
TP-000321374         Anita Rene Classen                       Teacher              Johannesburg         NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    2014-10-17 07:57:00.000 NULL                    NULL                    NULL
TP-000322789         Samuel Mohlamnyane                       Teacher              Port Elizabeth       NULL                    NULL                    2014-10-18 07:23:00.000 NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL
TP-000323383         Lerato Manyanka                          Teacher              Bedfordview          NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    2014-10-17 08:57:00.000 2014-10-16 06:51:00.000 NULL                    NULL
TP-000324511         Anthonysia White                         Teacher              Durbanville          NULL                    NULL                    2014-10-18 12:26:00.000 NULL                    NULL                    2014-10-15 07:53:00.000 NULL
TP-000346529         Edmos Dube                               Teacher              Melrose              NULL                    NULL                    2014-10-18 07:47:00.000 NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL
```

Comment: Hi jpw, Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. In addition to the solution you provided, the filter you used in limiting date range just. "WHERE [Day Attended > (GETDATE() - 7) " you filtering to look at all attendance (greater than 7 days back) at the same time as the system time(time you running the query). To ensure that all times are included for the day we can substitute "getdate() - 7" with "DATEADD(d,-7,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))". Without a doubt this is what I am looking for. Thank you

Comment: @user1538257 Indeed, `DATEADD(d,-7,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))` would be better. Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Oh yes you definitely answered my question. Just as an addition say now I want my aliases to change from just Day1, Day2, etc I then add a generic date something like Day1(20-10-2014), Day2 (19-10-2014), if you have a clue of how I can do that I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @user1538257 sure I know how to do that it's easy, but let me get back later - I'm traveling at the moment. Btw, what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: am using sql server 2012

Comment: @user1538257 I just got back from work and had another look at this and it turns out to be a lot harder than I anticipated and I can't quite figure out how to do that last part, sorry.